# where does visual studio C++ store files

Tags: visual-studio

I am confused by how Visual studio does handle project files. I added some headers, c++ source files, and raw files to my project, I can find them on the visual studio interface, but when navigating to the directory where the project is being stored on my computer I don't find the files I added. This way I can't add the project's files to git.

[Root of the project's folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Afr.png)

[Project1 folder that is in the root of the project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEz4p.png)

I tried looking in different sub folders of the root folder where my project is saved locally on my machine.

Comment: They're inside `Project1`, right?

Comment: No, but after I created the project Project1, I used Right click > Add > Add existing Item

Comment: It seemd like VS is not copying the files I am adding through Add existing Item, it just uses them and lets them where they are

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "where they are".  Visual Studio does not copy files.  It just adds the paths to your project.

Comment: ALright, I got the thing. I still need some clarification: In the images I attached, there are Debug/Release folders at different levels of the folder hierarchy. I find it a bit complex. Is there a specific meaning for each folder, how should I interpret the hierarchy? Also I want to add some post build commands to copy some resources files to the output using xcopy, do I need to use the full path of the original file, or is there a way to reference them relatively to the visual studio project (or solution if it is the most appropriate name)?

Comment: Debug, Release, x64/Debug and x64/Release are OUTPUT directories.  That's where the compiled binaries will be stored.  They're done that way so they don't conflict.  You can't mix debug objects and release objects, and of course you can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit objects.

Comment: Ok and why /Debug and /Project1/Debug?

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the Project / Solution concept in visual studio, although not familiar with the difference of both folders, the one for the solution seems to be the content of the bin and the other contains intermediate build object.. I am just guessing

Comment: Alright, thanks for the assistance, it is not very clear but I think I need to do more reading

Comment: If it is any comfort, I also find their decisions confusing, and I usually rewrite the vcxproj file to enforce a more sane layout.

Comment: Storing the final build result in the *solution* directory ensures that the output of all projects in the solution end up in the same place.  Important to create debuggable multi-project solutions, no DLL Hell hassle finding back libraries at runtime.